# I am stuck loading into the Outfitter

Tags: ps3, red-dead-redemption

When I enter an Online match on the GOTY edition for the PS3 and go to my Outfitter, it is stuck loading. The load screens transition and the revolver chamber keeps spinning and emptying so it isn't a crash. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to any random game that is **not Free Roam** and go to the Outfitter from there.